# Lock outside or inside Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I'm learning thread safety and I can't seem to find a clear answer to a question when searching online.

What is the difference and the impacts between this:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    new Thread () {
        public void run() {
            // critical section
        }
    }.start();
}
```

and this:

```
new Thread () {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // critical section
        }
    }
}.start();
```

To give you a context, I'm coding a small lab and the approach is 'one thread per request' so each time the method is called, either one of those above is executed to the 'critical section' is executed in it's own thread.

So having the lock inside or outside the Thread has an impact? Does each thread 'inherit' the lock or does it have to be within each thread to be fully thread-safe?

Comment: The first one is useless.

Comment: The first one release lock after `thread.start` , the second one is correct that waiting all code in `run method` finish before releasing lock

Comment: awesome! thanks :)

Comment: Why would you want to run a critical section in its own Thread? The point of a critical section is that only one thread can be in it at the same time, so why not run the section in the thread you're in, rather than a new thread? There's no benefit to a new thread, and a lot of drawbacks (takes longer, more memory use, more garbage to be collected)

Comment: It's intended to be that way. If I give you the full context you'd get it. This is just an extract ;)

Comment: Hint: then you dont have [mcve] here. The other comments are all correct - the first code is absolutely **meaningless**. You can rewrite it **without** the sync statement; and the exact same things can happen.

Comment: My question was perfectly answered in the first two comments thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

synchronizing just means that only one thread at a time can execute certain part of code

in the first example, only one thread at a time can create and start a new thread.  but notice that you are not protecting the critical section (multiple threads can execute their "run" method simultaneously)

```
synchronized (lock) {
    new Thread () {
        public void run() {
            // critical section
        }
    }.start();
}
```

in the second example, multiple threads can create and start a new thread, but only one thread at a time can execute the critical section (protected by "lock")

```
new Thread () {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // critical section
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: For the detailed explanation, you get the answer :)